# Cartopy subplot ticks & axes box line formatting

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm using cartopy to plot several areas of very different sizes in different subplot arrangements (1x2, 3x4 etc.), which makes it quite difficult to find consistent layout parameters. One issue is that longitude tick labels are overlapping for small areas. Is there a way to rotate them? I'm creating the grid and ticks as follows:

```
gridlines = map.gridlines(crs=crs, draw_labels=True, linewidth=linewidth, color='black', alpha=1.0, linestyle=':', zorder=13)
```

The other issue is that by downscaling the Geoaxes in the subplot arrangement, the bounding box' line thickness appears very wide. Is there a way to set it explicitely? Here's the command I'm using to add each Geoaxes subplot:

```
map = fig.add_subplot(nrows, ncols, 1 + nth_col + (ncols * nth_row), projection=ccrs.Mercator())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is any control provided for either of these.

Regarding rotated ticks: With some care you can add axis ticks, and rotate those with usual "axes.set_ticklabels(... rotation=X)".  But the gridline labels are *not* ticks, and you can't do this -- you can only control the position and formatting (via the exposed ticker and formatter objects).

Regarding the outline: again this does not appear to be the normal axes outline, and does not respond to the usual axes.set_frame_on() control.
I do find that "plt.gca().outline_path.set_linewidth" can be used.  I guess this is useful but probably not a futureproof solution.